# how can i sort python dict to nested list based on key value

Tags: python, arrays

I have a nested dictionary

```
 d = {'records':[
       {'name':abhi,'age':23,'dept':'cse'}, 
       {'name':anu,'age':20,'dept':'ece'},
       {'name':ammu,'age':25,'dept':'cse'},
       {'name':anju,'age':26,'dept':'ece'}
     ]}
```

but I want to have the dictionary rearranged, grouped by department.  I have done different methods, but did not get the desired result.

```
d = [
      [ {'name':abhi,'age':23,'dept':'cse'},
        {'name':ammu,'age':25,'dept':'cse'}
      ],
      [ {'name':anu,'age':20,'dept':'ece'},
        {'name':anju,'age':26,'dept':'ece'}
      ]
    ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a *list of dictionaries* within a dictionary. You can sort these dictionaries using standard [list sorting methods](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting):

```
d={'records':[{'name':'abhi','age':23,'dept':'cse'}, 
              {'name':'anu','age':20,'dept':'ece'},
              {'name':'ammu','age':25,'dept':'cse'},
              {'name':'anju','age':26,'dept':'ece'}]}

d['records'].sort(key = lambda x: x['name'])

>>> d['records']
[{'name': 'abhi', 'age': 23, 'dept': 'cse'}, {'name': 'ammu', 'age': 25, 'dept': 'cse'}, {'name': 'anju', 'age': 26, 'dept': 'ece'}, {'name': 'anu', 'age': 20, 'dept': 'ece'}]
```

For your particular case:

```
d['records'].sort(key = lambda x: (x['name'], x['dept']))
```

And then a list comprehension to group sublists with the same `dept` together:

```
my_list = [[i for i in d['records'] if i['dept'] == de] for de in {i['dept'] for i in d['records']}]

>>> my_list
[[{'name': 'anju', 'age': 26, 'dept': 'ece'}, {'name': 'anu', 'age': 20, 'dept': 'ece'}], [{'name': 'abhi', 'age': 23, 'dept': 'cse'}, {'name': 'ammu', 'age': 25, 'dept': 'cse'}]]
```

Comment: i need to get this as a single list for both same department  i want to sort it with department value
     [[{'name':abhi,'age':23,'dept':'cse'} 
    {'name':ammu,'age':25,'dept':'cse'}], 
     [{'name':anu,'age':20,'dept':'ece'},{'name':anju,'age':26,'dept':'ece'}]

Comment: i need to get it as same dipartment as 1 list and another as another list for looping purpose

Comment: Thank You VeryMuch